# opengl es: drawing a texture with fading gradient

Tags: opengl-es, gradient

I am completely new to opengl and need some help in drawing a texture with gradient applied over it.

Now I am drawing a texture with the following code:

```
glPushMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,fcr.texture);
glTranslatef(trans, 0, 0);
glScalef(sc,sc,1.0);
glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.4);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
```

In the above code `glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.4);` applies transparency to the drawn image. Now instead of a solid transparent color, I would like to apply a transparent gradient to the image so as to simulate the fading out effect.

Found this thread [iPhone OpenGL - How to gradient fade out a texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536763/iphone-opengl-how-to-gradient-fade-out-a-texture), which is the same as my question except I want the gradient to be applied to the main image itself instead of reflection. But I couldn't figure out the solution from answers given.

I guess I should use `glTexEnvi`, but then how to draw another image with the gradient?

Comment: Do you mean fading out in time, or just like a left to right gradient where the left side is non-transparent and the right side is fully transparent (or top/bottom, topleft/bottomright, etc)?

Comment: dont need fading animations over time, but just static fading effect as u said..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling glColor4f before drawing the quad, can you set a glColorPointer (or glVertexAttribPointer), such that each of the four vertices of your quad get a different alpha value?

i.e. RGBA values:

```
 (x,x,x,1)       (x,x,x,0)
     -----------------
     |               |
     |               |
     |               |
     |               |
     |               |
     |               |
     -----------------
  (x,x,x,1)      (x,x,x,0)
```

This would give you an alpha gradient from right to left.